# UIPagecontrol is not updating when my UIScrollViewscroll

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make a table whose cells have UIPageControls with ScrollViews in them. The ScrollViews work and the PageControls are there, but the PageControl does not update when scrolling happens except for on the bottom cell. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
  customCellForText *cell = [tableObj dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCellForText" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 80, 150, 100)];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    //[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];

    for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++){
      CGRect frame;
      frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
      frame.origin.y = 0;
      frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

      subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
      subview.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
      subview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
      [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];

    }

  pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc]init];
  pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count;
  pageControl.currentPage = 0;
  pageControl.hidesForSinglePage = YES;
  pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(170, 180, 100, 30);
  [cell.contentView addSubview:pageControl];
  [pageControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changePage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

  cell.nameLabel.text=@"amol";

  return cell;
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{
    // Update the page when more than 50% of the previous/next page is visible

    CGFloat pageWidth = sender.frame.size.width;
     int newPage = floor((sender.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
  self.pageControl.currentPage = newPage;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code to determine the page (the equation is wrong in your code):

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var page: Int = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = page
}
```

In Objective-C the code is:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.pageProfileControl.currentPage = page;
}
```

Comment: can you please write it in Objective-C?

Comment: You have to put this code in the custom cell class not in the UITableViewController class and set scrollview.delegate = self also in the custom cell implementation file.

Comment: M can you please give me some demo?

Comment: You should put the delegate method in the customCellForText .m file

Comment: I am confused which delegate method to implement in customCellForText.m file ,TableView Delegate or UIScrollView Delegate method ,? please help me...

Comment: The scrollviewDidScroll method should be placed in the customCellForText.m file. And change scrollView.delegate = self; to scrollView.delegate = cell;

Answer (score 0):

I found answer to my question ,Here is the right way to add sliding UIImageView on customCell using UIScrollView and UiPageControl,
May be this helps new guys like me...

Write this code in CustomCell.m file

```
  -(void)setScrollViewForImages{

      imageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"man-actor-Ashton-Kutcher-Wallpaper.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"man-curl.jpg"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"man-in-suit.jpg"],
                    nil];

      for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++)
          {

          //    CGRect frame;
          //    frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
          //    frame.origin.y = 0;
          //    frame.size.width = 200; //SCREEN_WIDTH;
          //

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;


        UIImageView *img=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        img.tag = i+1100;
        img.contentMode= UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        img.image=[imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:img];

          //self.scrollView.delegate = self;

        scrollView.delegate = self;

          }


       self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * imageArray.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);

        // self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;

      self.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageArray.count;
      [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

      [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{

      if (!pageControlBeingUsed)

          {

        CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;

          //int page = floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
        NSInteger page = (NSUInteger)floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x * 2.0f + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0f));

        self.pageControl.currentPage = page;

             }
    }

Call this method in cellForRowAtIndexPath
don't forget this line self.scrollView.delegate=cell;



     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
          static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
          customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
          if (cell==nil)
              {
             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"customCell" owner:self options:nil];
             cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
              }

           [cell setScrollViewForImages];

cell.scrollView.delegate=cell;
       cell.nameLbl.text = @"amol";
       return cell;
    }
```